# Count photons in laser beam emitted by a laser pointer

Tags: optics, particle-physics

Is it possible to count photons in laser beam?  It is a laser beam from a laser pointer. What device must I use if such is the case?

Comment: Hello! Please avoid writing your title in caps locks only. Thanks!

Comment: see this experiment single photon at a time  https://www.sps.ch/artikel/progresses/wave-particle-duality-of-light-for-the-classroom-13/

Comment: Are you interested in the quantum picture (coherent state => superposition state => number of photons not well-defined) or in the classical description?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Laser beam photon counting](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/163018/laser-beam-photon-counting)

Answer (score 2):

Usually each laser is specified by emitted maximum power and light wavelength. Using energy-power relation $$E=P\,t$$ and the fact that laser energy is the sum of energy of all photons emitted : $$ E=n~h\nu $$,
one can calculate total number of photons $n$, given laser power $P$, wavelength $\lambda$ and time window $t$ :
$$ n = \frac {P\lambda}{hc} ~t $$

For green laser pointer with power $5~\text{W}$, wavelength of $532~\text{nm}$, this gives about $10^{19}$ photons / second.

**EDIT**

As for the skeptics, here is my laser pointer.
[image]

$ 5000 ~ \text{mW} = 5 ~\text{W} $, so true- my laser is a bit more powerful than "ordinary ones".

Comment: Not sure what laser pointer you typically use, but mine has a 5 *milli*Watt power!

Comment: @Gilbert Given formula works for any power laser.

Comment: Yes indeed. I’m merely amused by your phrasing. You have my upvote!

Comment: Your photo said power < 5000mW so it could be anywhere between 0mW and 5000mW. For example, 0.5mW, 5mW, 50mW, 500mW, etc.

Comment: I know, that it's an upper power bound, we have to use some number from laser specification, I don't have any other number. If you do - please make other calculations. The thing is that formula is correct, so do not make silly word play. I don't believe that laser power can be _anything_, it's just manufacturer way to specify upper bound and to reflect the fact that power depends on batteries charge level, If batteries are drained, then of course - power will drop drastically. But other than that, using this given number in calculations I think is Ok.